# "Unable to locate package" when trying to install software

Tags: system-installation, system

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.  When I try to install an application, some packages can't be located.

I tried to use `sudo apt install` but some packages do not exist in Ubuntu when I search for the package name such as `libxmu` and `linuxbrew`.

```
E: Unable to locate package binutils
E: Unable to locate package tcsh python-dev
E: Unable to locate package libboost-python-devliblapack-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxmu-dev libxi-dev
E: Unable to locate package libmyslqclient-dev
E: Unable to locate package libbz2-dev libgsl-dev
E: Unable to locate package libtool
```

How can I fix this problem without reinstalling?

Comment: are you running `sudo apt update` before you attempt to run `sudo apt install`?  You should do this every time -- your system needs to update the list of available packages.  These packages are available in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: yes, every time I did that but still have the packages I mentioned unable to locate. you are right I checked of most of them available, that's why i think there something went wrong during installation Ubuntu [bionic]

Comment: Can you access any internet resources at all, like through your browser?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1256408/edit) your question with the verbatim unredacted output of both `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Please retain all line breaks and use proper formatting (each line of code should begin with four spaces).  I've also made an edit suggestion -- can you please review it to make sure that the edit is true to your question?